# Control breaking of overlong section titles

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking

I have following code:

```
\section{This is some long text and probably it will be broken}
```

I would like to prevent word division like:

```
This is some long text and pro-
bably it will be broken
```

And the second issue is to break it in a nice way, for example:

```
This is some long text and probably it will be
broken
```

looks bad, because only word 'broken' will be placed in second line. It would be nicer to do it in this way:

```
This is some long text and probably
it will be broken
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a manual line change in the title (and the optional argument of the `\section` command to prevent the line change from appearing in the headings and in the ToC). Another option would be to use the `\sloppy` command and non-breaking spaces (but this will probably produce a bad box):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section[This is some long text and probably it will be broken]{This is some long text and probably\\ it will be broken}

\section{\sloppy This is some long text and probably it~will~be~broken}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to brake the line in a part title that had custom line spacing. I tried a lot of solutions. The only thing that worked stably for me was

```
\usepackage{setspace} 
...

\begin{spacing}{1.1}
    \part{\sloppy Introduction and state~of~the~art}
\end{spacing}
```